# Installing an Android app : ADT vs Terminal

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, adb, adt

When an app is launched via ADT the avg. execution of a specific code took ~150ms (note the debugger is not attached)
When the same app is installed via adb and installed manually clicking on the icon the avg. time took to execute the same piece of code took ~58ms

So the difference in time is ~100ms - and there is no difference in code base except the way app is installed and launched.

Questions : 
What is the additional processing the app is doing when launched via ADT launcher? 
Did anyone came across this kind of scenario?
What are the best/recommended ways/tools to measure/instrument execution times.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The reasons being AOT vs JIT compilation. ADT defers AOT compilation and do it as when using the app, whereas adb do the AOT ahead and then install it. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fwMM6g7wpQ8&feature=youtu.be is helpful.